# Angularjs form submit, url as action iframe as target

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to do a form submit which has url as the action and target as iframe. I am getting the action url via an API call. If I hard coded the url in the controller it will work fine. But if i get the url from an API, click on the submit button will do nothing. What could be the problem here. Code is like following code snippets.

HTML

```html
<form action='{{trustedUrl}}'  method="POST"  target='iframe'>
   <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit", value="submit" />
 </form>
```

Java Script

```js
var testCtrl = ['$scope',function($scope){
  
  var pageInitialize = function(){
    $scope.trustedUrl = '';
    
    getUrl(function(data){
        trustedUrl = data.URL;
    
    });
  
  
  }
  
  
}]
```

Comment: There is a typo, change `target='iframe'`

Comment: pretty sure this is similar to the issue of `href` vs `ng-href` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref#!), but I don't believe there is any way to do this on an `action`.

Comment: have you tried ng-submit?

Comment: then how do I give the action url ?

Comment: Assign like `$scope.trustedUrl = data.URL;`

Comment: Can you see the action populated correctly on html page?

Answer (score 1):

You missed out **$scope** here

```
getUrl(function(data){
    $scope.trustedUrl = data.URL;
//-----^
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing $sce as follows:

```
var testCtrl = ['$scope','$sce',function($scope,$sce){
   var pageInitialize = function(){
      $scope.trustedUrl = '';

   getUrl(function(data){
      trustedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(data.URL);

   });
  }
}]
```

You can read more about $sce in the angular documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Angular 2

```
    <form target="frame" action="<Your URL to POST>" #form method="POST" hidden="hidden">
        <input name="token" value={{token}}>
    </form>
```

And call nativeElement.submit() from nginint() in your component.

similar here
[Angular way to submit form data to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886593/angular-way-to-submit-form-data-to-iframe/43005623#43005623)